# use an external js library in a node-red function

Tags: npm, node-red

I've installed a js library https://www.npmjs.com/package/fft with npm, how can I make this available in node-red functions ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is covered [Writing Functions](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules) sections of the Node-RED docs

You need to add npm modules to the `settings.js` file. You can find this file in `~/.node-red/`

The section you are looking for is the `functionGlobalContext` section.

```
...
functionGlobalContext: {
   fft: require('fft')
},
...
```

You would then access the module in the function node with the following:

```
var FFT = context.global.get('fft');
var fft = new FFT(n, inverse);
...
```

Also be careful where you installed the fft module, it needs to be either in `~/.node-red/node_modules` or installed globally so it is accessible to Node-RED.

EDIT:

More recent versions of Node-RED (v1.3.0 onward) have support for loading modules directly in the function node. The docs have been updated to [cover this](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#using-the-functionexternalmodules-option).

Comment: Thank you, I had already try this, but getting the error :

Error loading settings file: /home/pi/.node-red/settings.js
Error: Cannot find module 'ftt'

npm installed ftt in .node-red/node_modules.... I also tried to copy it to node-red/, but still the same problem...

Comment: Edit your original question to include the error (and always include **ALL** the information when you ask the question)

Comment: You have a typo in settings.js - the node is called `fft` and you have `ftt`