# 'Undefined' Exception in using external npm module in node-red with global context

Tags: node-red

I am trying to use a npm module in node-red, after doing some research I came accross the use of global context and so I did the following:

- Added a require in setting.js file of my node-red directory like so:

  `functionGlobalContext: { aesjs:require('aes-js'),},`
- Added a require to my red.js require (just in case) :

  `var aesjs = require('aes-js');`
- Installed the module `aes-js` globally and in node-red's `node_modules` directory
- I would call the module in a node function by invoking the global context:

  `var aesjs = global.get('aesjs');`

Problem is, once I execute my flow, the variable aesjs is undefined and I get the following debugging message:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ModeOfOperation' of undefined"
```

Which is in reference to the following code:

```
var aesjs = global.get('aesjs');
var aesEcb = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ecb(key);
```

In essence, I relied on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481130/use-an-external-js-library-in-a-node-red-function) but can't seem to understand why the variable is undefined, is it an issue of asynchronicity, if so how?

Here's an export of my experimental flow, just to make sure not stupid mistakes have been made:

```
[{"id":"205673d0.6ffd3c","type":"inject","z":"6affe53a.7dabcc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"{     \"id\": \"474192\" }","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":200,"y":420,"wires":[["f2c2083b.0afae8"]]},{"id":"f2c2083b.0afae8","type":"function","z":"6affe53a.7dabcc","name":"encrypt clientUid","func":"var aesjs = context.global.get('aesjs');\nvar gsm = msg.payload.id; \n\nvar key = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ];\n\nfunction gsmEncode(gsm,key)\n    {\n        var  textBytes=[];\n        \n        for ( i = 0; i < gsm.length; ++i)\n        {\n            var charCode = gsm.charCodeAt(i);\n            textBytes.push(charCode & 0xFF);\n        }\n        \n        return(bytesEncode(textBytes,key));\n    }\n\nfunction bytesEncode(bytes,key)\n    {\n        for ( i = bytes.length;i<16; ++i)\n            bytes.push(0);\n        \n        var aesEcb = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ecb(key);\n        var encryptedBytes = aesEcb.encrypt(bytes);\n        \n        return(Buffer.from(encryptedBytes).toString('base64'));\n    \n    }\n\nmsg.payload.encodedId = gsmEncode(gsm,key);\n\nreturn msg; ","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":480,"y":420,"wires":[["fab2be23.e888d"]]},{"id":"fab2be23.e888d","type":"debug","z":"6affe53a.7dabcc","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":810,"y":420,"wires":[]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything specifically wrong with what you describe and I have just checked I can access the `aes-js` module via `functionGlobalContext`, so there must be some missing detail in what you are doing.

You only need to install `aes-js` in the same directory as your `settings.js` file - by default `~/.node-red/`.

You should not modify `red.js`.

When Node-RED starts up check there are no error messages regarding your settings file.

Comment: Hi, on running node-red I get a message `Downloaded and installed NPM module aes-js`, not the worst message you'd expect ! This is puzzeling !

Comment: Added my experimental flow just to make sure I don't have some missing part or bug, I've looked it through, should work fine but you never know.

Comment: Why would Node-RED log anything about having downloaded and installed the module? Are you trying to use it with `node-red-contrib-npm` as well?